# Update Glob dependency on Jest packages

Tags: security, jestjs, glob, ts-jest, fortify

Since 12/01/2023 Fortify throw a vulnerability by version 1.0.6 of Inflight library. The last version of Jest has the last version of Glob fixed but their packages still have a vulnerable version on Glob (8xx version). Can you update the packages to the last version oh Glob to clean the Fortify & Snyk reports?

I've try with the script of this [post](https://github.com/isaacs/inflight/issues/5#issuecomment-1840959215) but still the vulnerability exists, in fact there is another one. Maybe I can try updating my Angular version to 16, but I think that if Jest package's has the dependency, our problems will keep on the Fortify reports.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

While going through SOC compliance, I ran into the same problem. The solution I opted in for,

1. Move all the Jest related packages from "dependencies" to "devDependencies" in your `package.json`
2. during your prod/demo servers deployment change your dependencies install to add production flag.

`pnpm i --production` or `npm i --production`

This will make sure to only install "dependencies" packages only in your prod/demo envs. However keep circle or whatever testing pipeline you have to usually pnpm install.

Prod stacks stay clean of any vul.